# Is is true that $\mathbb{Q}(x^2)(x) = \mathbb{Q}(x^2)[x] = \mathbb{Q}(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I am working on a proof and want to show this equality. It appears to be true, but I'm not sure of how to show it rigorously. I know the first equality hold since $x \in \mathbb{Q}(x)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(x^2)$.

Comment: Does $\frac{1}{1+x} \in \mathbb{Q}(x^2)[x]$?

Comment: @lhf Yes, $\frac 1{1 + x} = \frac 1 {1 - x^2} - \frac 1{1 - x^2} \cdot x$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+x} = \frac{1 - x}{1 - x^2}$. The OPs argument seems sound to me: $x$ is algebraic over ${\mathbb Q}(x^2)$, so ${\mathbb Q}(x^2)[x] = {\mathbb Q}(x^2)(x)$. This is all there is to it, since ${\mathbb Q}(x^2)(x) = {\mathbb Q}(x^2,x) = {\mathbb Q}(x)$. I'm not sure how more rigorous you'd want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We obviously have $\Bbb Q(x^2)(x) = \Bbb Q(x)$, as $x^2$ belongs to $\Bbb Q(x)$.

Thus it suffices to show that $\Bbb Q(x^2, x) = \Bbb Q(x^2)[x]$.

But this is simly because the element $x$ is algebraic (of degree $2$) over $\Bbb Q(x^2)$, as it is root of the polynomial $T^2 - x^2 \in \Bbb Q(x^2)[T]$.